# How to setState (and where it can be done better) when I receiving new props . I need to set them directly in state. в

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is

```
 componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {

   const returnItems = nextProps.returnItems.map(item => ({
      id: item.id,
      selected: false,
      quantity: 1,
    }));

    this.state?this.setState({ returnItems }):null;
  }`
```

I try to set my props directly to state but it gives me warnings hence does not 
The warning is following

> Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op

So basically it means that It can't update because the component is not mounted. But why is it saying that I can't understand

Comment: True, [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate) also says the same, that you shouldn't call setState in this method

Comment: You're running afoul of React's lifecycle in a way that risks an infinite loop. Instead, look into componentWillRecieveProps. I'd link but I'm on mobile.

Comment: Do you really want to keep `returnItems` in your props and in your state?

Comment: @Icepickle, in other persons case returnItems state contains more info than just the props returnsItems

Answer (score 0):

Before v16.3.0 you could update the state based on prop change in componentWillReceiveProps function and with a condition check

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if(!_.isEqual(nextProps.returnItems, this.props.returnItems)) {
       const returnItems = nextProps.returnItems.map(item => ({
          id: item.id,
          selected: false,
          quantity: 1,
       }));

       this.setState({ returnItems })
    }
}
```

From version 16.3.0 you would use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if(!_.isEqual(nextProps.returnItems, this.props.returnItems)) {
       const returnItems = nextProps.returnItems.map(item => ({
          id: item.id,
          selected: false,
          quantity: 1,
       }));

       return {returnItems }
    }
    return null
}
```

In your case you are getting an error because setState causes a re-render which trigger a `componentWillUpdate` and which in turn triggers a setState, thus an infinite loop. You need to conditionally check if the props changed before updating the state. Also please note that from version 16.3.0 `componentWillUpdate` is renamed to `UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

The best place to call `setState` when you receive props is `componentWillReceiveProps()`